# How to make speech bubble (callout) on SpriteKit iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game for children using `SpriteKit` framework in iOS.
In my game, there are many speech bubbles which should be drawn by code.

I googled around and found intructions about using `SKShapeNode` to do it, but I haven't found a full Objective-C source code.

Has anyone done this before?
[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you consulted the [SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html) documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the speech bubble you have already posted and display it as a SKSpriteNode with texture or image. Depending on your code set limitations, you can scale the y-axis for more or less text lines. Add SKLabelNodes to the bubble as children.

Comment: Using an SKSpriteNode's `centerRect` property you can scale only the centre and keep the corners of the bubble the same without pixelation.